# Как создать множество на основе уравнения?

Tags: javascript, математика, множества

Пытаюсь создать калькулятор числовых операций над множествами и столкнулся с проблемой. Мне надо создавать множества на основе уравнений, но ответом такого уравнения является диапазон значений с неизвестным шагом и неизвестным размером.

К примеру если создается множество чисел со свойством: x * 8 + 3, где x **любое** натуральное число, то множество должно состоять из чисел {11, 19, 27 ...(и до бесконечности)}.
А если x **любое** целое число? Тогда это множество будет состоять уже из {(от бесконечности)..., -21, -13, -5, 11, 19, 27 ...(и до бесконечности)}. Но х еще может быть **любым** действительным числом.

И после создания множества надо над ними еще и операции проводить, а как это сделать идей совсем нет

Примеры того, что я пытаюсь реализовать:

```
Для начала пользователь создает множества, к примеру:
A = {x| (x * 2) - 2, x ∈ N}
B = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

Далее он может выполнить операции над множествами:
A ∩ B
И по итогу должен отобразиться ответ: {2, 4}
```

```
Количество множеств может быть любое
A = {x| (x * 2) - 2, x ∈ N}
B = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
C = {-4, -1, 0}
D = (1, 2)

Далее он может выполнить операции над множествами:
(A ∩ C) ∪ (B ∩ D)
И по итогу должен отобразиться ответ: (пустое множество)
```

И т.д. (не уверен, на счет правильности ответов в примерах, но суть надеюсь я донес)

Comment: Как я понимаю, это учебное задание. Вы бы не могли просто дать его так, как оно сформулировано в оригинале, слово в слово?

Comment: @Harry Я создаю приложение для курсовой работы. Поэтому как такого сформулированного задания нет

Comment: А ели x действительное, то ваше множество ничем не отличается от R

Comment: И, кстати, во втором примере вы 3 пропустили

Comment: @AlexeyTen, все верно подмечено, только мне это ни чем не помогает

Comment: Ну мне всё ещё непонятно что же вы хотите в результате получить.

Comment: Мне кажется, что нужно капать в сторону функций и показывать только n значений.

Comment: Раз для курсовой — есть ТЗ на курсовую. Если нет — то упростите работу с множествами до реальной. Но "все числа вида 8x+3, где x — действительное число — это просто множество всех действительных чисел... :)

Comment: @Игорь, мне тоже так кажется, но возникает проблема с операциями над множествами. Если это будут функции, то не понятно, как выполнять объединение, пересечение и др.

Comment: @Harry, нет не правда, я же привел пример с тем, как будет выглядеть это множество. И что вы имеете в виду под "упростите работу с множествами до реальной"?

Comment: Вы привели для **натуральных** и **целых** x. И написали *Но х еще может быть любым действительным числом*. Все, для любого действительного y можно найти такое x, что `8x+3==y`. В любом случае вы столкнетесь с точностью представления действительных чисел... Реальной — с конечными множествами. Реализуйте себе что-то типа С++'ного `set`. Пока — при таком условии (ни точного описания задания членов множества, ни реализуемых операций над ним (*калькулятор числовых операций над множествами* — не описание!), ни ввода-вывода) никакой более-менее детальный ответ невозможен.

Comment: Напишите конкретных примеров множеств и операций

Comment: @Harry, на сколько я понимаю в js тоже есть set'ы. И я по началу хотел использовать, но я не знаю, что делать с бесконечными множествами

Comment: @Harry, о вещественных числах не может быть и речи. В текущей постановке обещано доказать большую теорему Ферма, например. Или решать произвольные диофантовы уравнения. Это всё про натуральные числа. ТС не понимает на что он замахнулся.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Именно поэтому я и написал *упростите работу с множествами до реальной*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы продвинутся сделайте множества объектами. Набор операций: проверка принадлежности числа множеству, пересечение, объединение. Строить каноническое представление множества в виде набора элементов не надо. Например: чтобы проверить принадлежит ли число объединению, достаточно проверить что принадлежит одному из элементов объединения.

В итоге вы будете иметь набор классов, который реализуют один интерфейс и с которыми можно оперировать.

Теперь плохие новости: проверка множества на пустоту не является алгоритмически разрешимой задачей. На целых числах вы можете составить диофантово уравнение, а про них известно что наличие корней у диофантова уравнения нельзя вычислить ([десятая проблема Гильберта](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%93%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0)).

В качестве шутки кусочек большой теорема Ферма:

```
const zero = ...; // множество из одного нуля
const N = ...; // натуральные числа
const cubes = map(N, i => i ** 3); // множество всех кубов натуральных чисел
const s = add(cubes, cubes); // x^3 + y^3, поэлементная сумма двух множеств
const d = sub(s, cubes); // x^3 + y^3 - z^3, поэлементная разница
const t = intersection(d, zero); // x^3 + y^3 - z^3 = 0
console.log(t.is_empty());
```

На последний вопрос вы можете ответить положительно только если обладаете хорошими знаниями в теории чисел.

Хорошие новости:

1. если вы ограничитесь конечными множествами, всё просто;
2. если к ним добавить арифметические прогрессии, то всё усложнится, но справиться можно;
3. если добавить вторые степени, то всё становится очень сложно, но алгоритмически эта задача разрешима, хотя сложновата для курсовой;
4. дальше ходить не надо.

Comment: Кажется у автора нет операции map. Если же ограничится только множествами вида a*n+b и конечными наборами ю, то может что-то и выйдет.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, ``A = {x| (x * 2) - 2, x ∈ N}` - операция `map` во всей красе.

Comment: В смысле что дальше у автора нет операции `x \in A`. Да и, если я правильно понимаю первый параграф, в формуле может быть не любое выражение. Хотя может я и не прав, это надо у автора спрашивать.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, если разрешить бесконечные множества, поэлементные суммы, поэлементные произведения, тогда проверка пустоты множества становится невычислима. Что-то можно сделать только для первых и вторых степеней в уравнениях.

Comment: Ну вот мне кажется что у автора только первые степени (арифметические прогрессии), т. е. второй пункт вашей классификации.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, прогрессии сводятся к конечным множествам, так как можно показать, что все множества будут подмножествами периодических последовательностей, у которых легко вычислить оценку периода и даже сам период. Вот только тот период растёт довольно быстро и скоро вылезет из `double`. Для целых надо переходить на `BigInt`. Для вещественных вообще ничего сделать нельзя, если только не подменить их рациональными. Могу себе представить решение уравнения `xx = 2`. :)

Answer (score -1):

Разумеется,нужно быть математиком чтобы довести задачу до логического завершения, а она не из простых. Думаю, Вам нужно это создать `class` моножества, где указывать при инициализации его свойства например диапазон,либо формулу для вычисления чтобы можно было проверять находится ли что-то в данном диапазоне.

Далее нужно реализовать методы над множествами в этом классе, результатом из выполнения должен создаваться новый экземпляр (возможно что его определением будет несколько формул)

Так же понадобится как минимум один `парсер` выражений для записи математических выражений средствами `JavaScript`.

Я добавил небольшой пример, чтобы не быть голословным, он не решает всех перечисленных задач в частности `парсинга инициализации` для любой записи, возврата множества в виде нового экземпляра - т.к. это зависит от реализации `парсинга` (но суть надеюсь я донес)

Для вывода результатов можно использовать нативный класс `Set`

```js
class mySet {
  constructor(definition) {
    this.parse(definition)
  }
  parse(definition){
    if (definition === `{x | (x * 2) - 2, x ∈ N}`){
      this.test =  new Function('x', 'return x | (x * 2) - 2')  
      this.type = 'Function'
      this.belong = 'N'  
    } else if (definition === '{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}'){
      this.test =  new Function('x', 'return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]')
      this.type = 'Array'  
      this.belong = 'Any'
    }
  }

  cross(N){
    if(N.type ==='Array' && this.type === 'Function'){
      return N.test().filter(e => e === this.test(e))
        .map(e => this.test(e))
    } else if (N.type ==='Function' && this.type === 'Array'){
      return this.test().filter(e => e === N.test(e))
        .map(e => N.test(e))
    }
  }

} 

const m = new mySet('{x | (x * 2) - 2, x ∈ N}')
const n = new mySet('{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}')

console.log(m.cross(n))
console.log(n.cross(m))
```

Что касается бесконечностей, то я к сожалению не математик, но думаю что в  JS c ними все хорошо:

```js
const a = 1;
const b = -10000000000;
const c = Infinity;

console.log(b > -Infinity)
console.log(a < Infinity)
console.log(c < Infinity)
```